# How to filter only nested related django objects?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have a model representing a room and a module. A module can have multiple rooms. Here is the get request result for my module object -

```
{
            "module_id": 4,
            "rooms": [
                {
                    "room_id": 2,
                    "title": "4",
                    "desc": "22",
                    "level": "2",
                    "is_deleted": true,
                },
                {
                    "room_id": 3,
                    "title": "3",
                    "desc": "22",
                    "level": "2",
                    "is_deleted": false,
                }
            ],
            "title": "4",
            "desc": "sdsdsdss",
            "is_deleted": false,
        }
```

Now I want the get request of modules to show all the modules and the rooms contained in each module should have is_deleted=False.
In other words, I don't want room with room_id=2 to be shown in the get request.

Here is my views.py file -

```
class add_module(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        module = Module.objects.filter(is_deleted=False, rooms__is_deleted=False)
        module_serializer = ModuleSerializer(module, many=True)
        return Response(module_serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Here is my serializer file for module -

```
class ModuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rooms = RoomSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Module
        fields = "__all__"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specific prefetch in queryset, like as blow:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

module = Module.objects.filter(
    is_deleted=False
).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        "rooms",
        queryset=Room.objects.filter(is_deleted=False)
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks man! Thats exactly what I wanted!